# Extract the specific columns and strings from a file using linux or python

Tags: python, linux, pattern-matching, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have encountered a problem when dealing with a 12 Gb file. I'm a newbie when it comes to linux. I hope someone here could help me, any suggestions are appreciated.

**I have a file named *phase_3.vcf* which is like these:**

```
##INFO=<ID=EAS_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the EAS populations">                            
##INFO=<ID=EUR_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the EUR populations">                            
##INFO=<ID=AFR_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the AFR populations">                            
##INFO=<ID=AMR_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the AMR populations">                            
##INFO=<ID=SAS_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the SAS populations">                
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  .   .    dbSNP_150;E_Freq;E_1000G;EAS_AF=0.3363;SAS_AF=0.4949;AFR_AF=0.4909
1   10235   rs540431307 T   TA  .   .   dbSNP_150;E_Freq;E_1000G;EAS_AF=0.0000;AMR_AF=0.0014;
1   10352   rs555500075 T   TA  .   .   dbSNP_150;EAS_AF=0.4306;EUR_AF=0.4264;SAS_AF=0.4192;
1   10505   rs548419688 A   T   .   .   TSA=SNV;E_Freq;EAS_AF=0.0000;AMR_AF=0.0000;AFR_AF=0.0008
1   10506   rs568405545 C   G   .   .   dbSNP_150;TSA=SNV;MA=G;MAF=0.000199681;EAS_AF=0.0000;
```

**And I wanna keep the first 5 columns and the strings "EAS_AF=" and the numbers followed them.**

To make it simple, the expected form of the outcome named ***result.txt*** should be like these:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT INFO
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  EAS_AF=0.3363
1   10235   rs540431307 T   TA  EAS_AF=0.0000
1   10352   rs555500075 T   TA  EAS_AF=0.4306
1   10505   rs548419688 A   T   EAS_AF=0.0000
1   10511   rs534229142 G   A   EAS_AF=0.0000
1   10539   rs537182016 C   A   EAS_AF=0.0000
```

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like Pandas would be a good place to start: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @dashiell Code I've tried: 'awk '/EAS_AF/ {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5}' 1000GENOMES-phase_3.vcf' but I dont know how to extract the strings "EAS_AF="

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is in a very common bioinformatics-format(vcf). So there are tools in bioinformatics specifically designed to solve your task:
For example [bcftools](https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/wiki/HOWTOs) has an option to remove all INFO-elements besides one.

The downside of this tool is, that it strictly requires vcf-format. So it would produce errors on your example. But I think you shortened the header for this post and it should be ok on your original file. To make it usable for me I had to adjust the header like described in the [format definition](http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-40/) by adding the fileformat and an INFO line in the header for every different INFO you have annotated in your variants:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##INFO=<ID=dbSNP_150,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="has dbSNP 150 entry">
##INFO=<ID=E_Freq,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="has E_Freq entry">
##INFO=<ID=E_1000G,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="has E_1000G entry">
##INFO=<ID=EAS_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the EAS populations">
##INFO=<ID=EUR_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the EUR populations">
##INFO=<ID=AFR_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the AFR populations">
##INFO=<ID=AMR_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the AMR populations">
##INFO=<ID=SAS_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the SAS populations">
##INFO=<ID=TSA,Number=1,Type=String,Description="No idea">
##INFO=<ID=MA,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Minor Allele">
##INFO=<ID=MAF,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Minor Allele Frequency">
##contig=<ID=1>
##bcftools_annotateVersion=1.4-23-ga468a83+htslib-1.4-34-g8e1be4a
##bcftools_annotateCommand=annotate -x QUAL test2.vcf.gz; Date=Thu Jun 28 17:58:17 2018
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1       10177   rs367896724     A       AC      .       .       dbSNP_150;E_Freq;E_1000G;EAS_AF=0.3363;SAS_AF=0.4949;AFR_AF=0.4909
1       10235   rs540431307     T       TA      .       .       dbSNP_150;E_Freq;E_1000G;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0.0014
1       10352   rs555500075     T       TA      .       .       dbSNP_150;EAS_AF=0.4306;EUR_AF=0.4264;SAS_AF=0.4192
1       10505   rs548419688     A       T       .       .       TSA=SNV;E_Freq;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0.0008
1       10506   rs568405545     C       G       .       .       dbSNP_150;TSA=SNV;MA=G;MAF=0.000199681;EAS_AF=0
```

Depending on your header you might have to take two additional steps to use this tool. First is to zip your input with bgzip:

```
bgzip phase_3.vcf
```

Second is making an tabix-index to enable fast access to your zipped file (this creates an additional file phase_3.vcf.gz.tbi as output):

```
tabix phase_3.vcf.gz
```

The actual call to bcftools after your input is in the right format is just:

```
bcftools annotate -x ^INFO/EAS_AF phase_3.vcf.gz >phase_3_output.vcf
```

With this steps I get something quite close to your desired output:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##INFO=<ID=EAS_AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele frequency in the EAS populations">
##contig=<ID=1>
##bcftools_annotateVersion=1.4-23-ga468a83+htslib-1.4-34-g8e1be4a
##bcftools_annotateCommand=annotate -x ^INFO/EAS_AF test2.vcf.gz; Date=Thu Jun 28 17:59:04 2018
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1       10177   rs367896724     A       AC      .       .       EAS_AF=0.3363
1       10235   rs540431307     T       TA      .       .       EAS_AF=0
1       10352   rs555500075     T       TA      .       .       EAS_AF=0.4306
1       10505   rs548419688     A       T       .       .       EAS_AF=0
1       10506   rs568405545     C       G       .       .       EAS_AF=0
```

Removing the first few lines with head, removing the QUAL and FILTER column with cut and rewriting 0 to 0.0000 with sed completets your task:

```
bcftools annotate -x ^INFO/EAS_AF phase_3.vcf.gz | tail -n +7 | cut -f1-5,8 |sed 's/=0$/=0.0000/g' >phase_3_output_finished.vcf
```

And you get the desired result:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT INFO
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  EAS_AF=0.3363
1   10235   rs540431307 T   TA  EAS_AF=0.0000
1   10352   rs555500075 T   TA  EAS_AF=0.4306
1   10505   rs548419688 A   T   EAS_AF=0.0000
1   10511   rs534229142 G   A   EAS_AF=0.0000
1   10539   rs537182016 C   A   EAS_AF=0.0000
```

Depending on what your final goal is, you might even find ways to reach it without this step discussed here by finding out about the options of tools like [bcftools](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools-man.html).

Because you are working with bioinformatics data you might find further help in the according communities like [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) or [bioinformatics.stackexchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the first lines if not needed and then use pandas to import csv and name the dataframe's columns

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv('/example.csv',names=['Column1','Column2'....])
```

edit : this is a python script, you'll need to install python in your linux system or use the one built in version.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do this in python, how to extact the strings "ESA_AF=" and the numbers followed is the most difficult part for me.